# NSString won't work in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

i'm starting to learn Objective C from today actually. I have a very little program which will print my name and age. I get the age to be printed but not the name. Instead of printing the name as a String it prints a number. Here's the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {

    NSString *name;
    int age;

}

-(void) setAge:(int)a;
-(void) setName:(NSString*) n;

-(int)age;
-(NSString*) name;

-(void) print;

@end

@implementation Person

-(void)setAge:(int) a{
    age = a;
}

-(void)setName:(NSString*) n{
    [n retain];
    [name release];
    name = n;
}

-(int)age{
    return age;
}

-(NSString*) name{
    return name;
}

-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"I'm %i, i'm %i years old", name, age);
}

@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    Person *p = [[Person alloc]init];

    [p setAge: 26];
    [p setName: @"Johnny"];
    [p print];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

From that i get this print: I'm 4176, i'm 26 years old. 
Why i'm i getting the 4176?
I don't understand :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your parents were just really into numbers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the format string `%i` you are telling `NSLog` that you want to print an integer, and it is printing the address in memory of the string (that is, the value of pointer `name`). Change your format string to tell it you want to print the string representation of the object pointed to by `name`, by using `%@`:

```
NSLog(@"I'm %@, i'm %i years old", name, age);
```

Comment: right how could i miss that. %i %d %f %@ To print values int, double, float, string. A newbie mistake i guess. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How are you printing it? My bet is you are not printing it right. Try printing it in the log like this

```
   NSLog(@"I'm %@, i'm %d years old", name, age);
```

Her's the table in case someone has same trouble [NSString Formating Table](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)